# how to automate non Java Script form for login into a mobile app?

Tags: java, automation, protractor, angularjs-e2e, appium-ios

I am trying to automate our mobile application(It is an angular app). We have recently implemented token server into all of our apps. The login form (spoof page) for our app is not a Java Script form. I am not sure how to automate that or may be skip that and write the code to go directly into the app. Kindly help.

Comment: When you say its not a Javascript form, does that means its not HTML at?  Or that its basic HTML without Javascript?  If its not HTML, what is it?

Answer (score -1):

You need to automate your login or ataff like that? You can embed your Angular App in a native mobile app? becouse is possible save de credential in a mobile and then pass that for your app in a webview. I use this thinks in Android. 
Regards